# Can not set gradient to button. Android

Tags: android-layout

I tried this [Android: Setting up custom gradient for button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956305/android-setting-up-custom-gradient-for-button) 
and other solutions but nothing works. Can anybody suggest anything else?

By the way, I use Material Theme. but this

[How to set a gradient background to a Material Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52371234/how-to-set-a-gradient-background-to-a-material-button)

solution also doesn't help

Comment: Hey, please share the code of where the button is and the gradient that you're trying to add. It's a bit difficult to help you like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change yout button to androidx.appcompat.windget.AppCompatButton and it resolves